# Enable login as root not working in ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ssh

i changed the  PermitRootLogin to yes in my sshd_config to connect to my server as root but i does'nt work im new to ubuntu and i dont know how to make it please help me

Comment: The root user is disabled for a very good reason.  Especially as a new user it is not recommended to enable the root user. It's really not necessary either since you can use `sudo` before commands to run individual commands as root.  You can also use `sudo su` to enter a bash session where all commands are run as if they were the root user.

Comment: i'm trying to install my ceph cluster in containers and i need the root access but i'm gonna disable it after finishing  my work any way i'm grateful   for your advice  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to provide a method for authenticating the root user - either by enabling the root password (not recommended - for security reasons) or by creating a public-private key pair for root.

If you do the latter, you may as well change `PermitRootLogin yes` to `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` - which iirc is the default anyhow.

Comment: yeah i opened up the shadow file and i found out that the root password is disabled so i made a new password and everything just work fine thank you for your help i need to install some packages and disable it any way